# Separar Array dentro de objeto

Tags: javascript, array, angular, ionic3

Tenho um array dentro de um objeto, gostaria de saber como faço para separar os itens nome_servico e valor_servico. Não sei se existe uma maneira de fazer isso no próprio html...

```js
pedido{id_pedido:"17",
id_usuario:"34",
nome_servico:"Servico 01,Servico 02,Servico 03"
valor_servico:"250,200,380",
total_servico:"830"}
```

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of pedido">    
  <div>{{item.nome_servico}}</div>
  <div>{{item.valor_servico}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nesse caso é só chamar no HTML mesmo: `pedido.nome_servico`.

Comment: Não vai funcionar o `for` visto que o objeto tem apenas um grupo de valores.

Comment: @DiegoSouza, o problema é que no html vem tudo junto 250,200,380

Comment: Ahhh. Mas de onde vem esses valores?

Comment: do banco, bem como um objeto mesmo, conforme mostrado ali...

Comment: Então, mas seria interessante vir do banco certo já pra você usar no `for` como um objeto. Assim você teria muito trabalho.

Comment: eu sei, mas aí entro num problema de salvar, o qual já consegui assim, por isso estou tentando desta forma...

Comment: E como você queria mostrar esses dados?

Comment: Separado, tipo assim:

Comment: Servico 01 - 200
Servico 02 - 250
Servico 03 - 380

Answer (score 2):

```
pedido = {
  id_pedido: "17",
  id_usuario: "34",
  nome_servico: "Servico 01,Servico 02,Servico 03",
  valor_servico: "250,200,380",
  total_servico: "830"
};

let arrSer = pedido.nome_servico.split(',');
let arrVal = pedido.valor_servico.split(',');

pedido.nome_servico = arrSer;
pedido.valor_servico = arrVal;
```

### HTML

```
<div *ngFor="let item of pedido.nome_servico; let i = index" [attr.data-index]="i">    
  <div>{{item}} - {{pedido.valor_servico[i]}}</div>
</div>
```